# Regex-matching a dictionary efficiently in Python

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary of word:count pairs in my Python script. From this dictionary, I would like to extract the entries matching any item in a list of strings.

I have found a working solution using regular expressions (see below), but it takes **forever** (~ 10 hours for a run). I feel there must be a faster way of doings this - do you guys have any input / ideas on how to improve my code?

```
import re

dicti={'the':20, 'a':10, 'over':2}
regex_list=['the', 'an?'] 

extractddicti= {k:v for k,v in dicti.items() if any (re.match("^"+regex+"$",k) for regex in regex_list)}
```

In reality, the dictionary has about 60,000 entries, the regex_list is ~ 1,000. The items in the regex list are regex strings, i.e. contain special characters like *?*, parentheses such as *(a|b|c)*, etc. They might match several entries in the dictionary.

#### Update / Edit

(see the accepted answer for an even better implementation of the same idea)

Following the advice of Keozon and others, I first compiled my regexes like so:

```
regex_list=['the', 'an?']
regex_list_compiled=[re.compile("^"+i+"$") for i in regex_list]
```

and then slightly adapted my search function:

```
extractddicti= {k:v for k,v in dicti.items() if any (re.match(regex,k) for regex in regex_list_compiled)}
```

The performance difference is quite breathtaking: A test run with a dictionary of 14800 items and a list of 1,100 regexes took 34 minutes without compilation, slightly less than one (!) minute with compilation. Did not expect it to be so dramatic. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: In your full version, are you compiling the regular expressions in the list? If not, do so. This is the exact reason the compile option exists. As it is, each regex is being compiled each time it's compared to a string. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile

Comment: Using `dicti.iteritems()` would offer a small improvement (unless this is python3). But more importantly, make sure your regexes don't suffer from [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and assume that your _real_ regexes are more complex.  Because using a regex to search for 'the' might not be the fastest method. ie. if you are searching for simple strings use str.find

Comment: Also, make sure you use raw string literals in your regular expression definitions, or you may encounter surprising behavior (`r'the'` instead of `'the'`)

Comment: `re.match` implies beginning of string, so the `^` is unnecessary (unless it is multi-line).  If you are on Python 3 you might consider `re.fullmatch`.

Comment: It might end up being faster to compile one regex which is the alternation of all the other regexes - I don't know how python optimizes them, but consider the case of `r'ab', r'ac'` as regexes. If your input is `bb`, both regexes will be attempted and will fail, but it's possible that a compiled regex would optimize it down to a single check. Profile it.

Comment: From a quick check with `re.compile(..., re.DEBUG)` it looks like it doesn't optimize - you'd have to do it by hand.

Comment: @cdarke good point! but will this make a difference in terms of computation time? (still on Python 2..)

Comment: @Daenyth interesting -- just to make sure i understand: doing *[(a|b|c)]* instead of *[a,b,c]*?

Comment: @Keozon thanks, that's a good idea! i have actually tried that but didn't really follow thru. ill give it a shot and see what it does!

Comment: If, after following the advice of the various comments and answers here, you still don't get the performance you need, I would recommend posting some of the regular expressions and actual keys, as that regex is a micro language in itself, and a lot of optimizations can occur there. Also, you could split the regex list into 2-4 parts and use multiprocessing, if multiple cores are available.

Comment: @patrick yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Daenyth cool, thanks! that does make sense, but as i have ~ 1,000 items in that list&can get enough improvement just out of compiling, i might not implement that...

Comment: @patrick:  hard to say, I doubt it will be huge.  It's worth including the `$` in the compiled regular expression (as others have said) rather than using `+` to continually generate a new string object.  As they say "every little helps".  Ah, I see you have done that, I missed the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling the regular expressions once rather than each time you use them would probably gain you a fair bit of performance improvement. So you'd have something like:

```
import re

dicti={'the':20, 'a':10, 'over':2}
patterns=['the', 'an?'] 
regex_matches = [re.compile("^"+pattern+"$").match for pattern in patterns]

extractddicti= {k:v for k,v in dicti.items()
                if any (regex_match(k) for regex_match in regex_matches)}
```

Comment: Also, for a bit of extra speed, you can do `regex_match = regex.match` and then call `regex_match` inside the comprehension.  It's typically a micro-optimization to do this, but if you have a large loop it can help.

Comment: Thanks @SethMMorton - good point, I've updated my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

What about joining the dict.keys in a single string to reduce number of loops? It seems faster here:

```
import re, random, string

#Generate random dictionary
dicti={''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5)):i for i in range(1000000)}

#Using ; as separator, you can find any match with [^;]
regex_list=['TH[^;]*', 'A[^;]*'] 
joined_keys = ';' + ';'.join(dicti.keys()) + ';'

extractddicti = {i[1:-1]:dicti[i[1:-1]] for sublist in 
                [re.findall(';'+k+';', joined_keys) for k in regex_list] 
                for i in sublist}
```

Timeit results for 10 loops:

```
╔════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ Algorithm  ║     Time (sec)     ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ Mine       ║ 2.116118321594911  ║
║ E. Gordon  ║ 20.956314717412653 ║
╚════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

## UPDATE

As @E. Gordon suggested you should change separator to newline `\n`, then you are able to use ^ and $ special operators with `re.MULTILINE`.

```
regex_list=['.*TH', 'AN.*'] 

joined_keys = '\n'.join(dicti.keys())   
all_regex = "^" + "$|^".join(regex_list) + "$" 
matched_keys = re.findall(all_regex, joined_keys, re.MULTILINE)

dicti_match = {k:dicti[k] for k in matched_keys}
```

Comment: If you join up the keys then you'll get erroneous matches - e.g. if you join up the strings 'th' and 'e', then you'd get a match against 'the'. Could be an interesting line of thought though - perhaps if you joined up the keys with newlines or some other appropriate delimiter?

Comment: @caiohamamura thanks for your input; I went with E. Gordon's answer here as it was up earlier and easier to implement, but will try yours later if I need more speed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem looks very much like the ad blocking problem. The [Easylist](https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet) is similar to your regex list but includes urls and url patterns.

In general regular expression matching is relatively fast. Yet, as you have already seen, it is not as fast as not running it, also common regular expression libraries are [not optimized for large disjunctions](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) like yours.

Your regex dictionary also contains full words. A [Trie](https://github.com/pytries/marisa-trie) or, if memory is an issue, a [DAWG](https://github.com/pytries/DAWG) would be perfect to match the full word portion of the regex dictionary.

The remaining problem is matching a large input to a large set of regexes, and a pre-filtering approach works very well in such cases: first check if there is a plausible match, and only if there is a plausible match then run the full regex match. i.e. in order for the 'an?' regex to match, the string has to have 'an' in it. [Suffix trees](https://github.com/JDonner/SuffixTree) are perfect for searching such substrings. You probably would want to add a string begin and string end marker if your regexes are always full matches. Of course you could also build a trie or dawg of the set of fixed strings and start a new search at every character. The same effect [can be implemented more efficiently](https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/fast-string-matching/) with a deterministic finite state automaton using a powerful automaton library.

Hopefully, this method will get rid of the need to run regex matching for a large portion of your input. Once you have to run the regular expression match, you can go with the python regex implementations in other answers.